# Add Label with Image in DialogViewController in IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, tableview, dialogviewcontroller

I am creating SlideNavigation Drawer in ios(Xamarin). and I have created with help of below link

https://github.com/thedillonb/MonoTouch.SlideoutNavigation

The code is working fine as I want.

**Code :**

```
class DummyControllerLeft : DialogViewController
    {
        float labelHeight;

        UIImageView profileImage;

        public DummyControllerLeft()
           : base(UITableViewStyle.Plain, new RootElement(""))
        {
            this.labelHeight = labelHeight;

            Root.Add(new Section()
            {
                new StyledStringElement("Home", () => NavigationController.PushViewController(new HomeViewController(), true)) { TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear, Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica-Bold", 16f) },

            });
            TableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
            TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f);

        }
}
```

But As you can see I have only able to add `String` name in my code case it is "Home". Now I want to add `Image`.

I search lot's of thing in google and SO. But nothing is work me.

Any Help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Image property of     `StyledStringElement`
That will solve your problem.

```
StyledStringElement home = new StyledStringElement ("Home", () => NavigationController.PushViewController (new HomeViewController (), true)) { TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
home.Image = new UIImage ("noimage.png");

Root.Add (new Section () {
                        home
                    });
```